# CSV to Excel sheet again

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a problem.

I know it's possible to make from a excel sheet a csv file delimited by comma's. But is there a way to transfer it back to a normal excel sheet with having back the same table structure as before it was saved as a csv file?

Any help or input would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of this question is that you have a Spreadsheet (XLS) that you want to save as a CSV to export the data to another system.

Choose File > Save As...

In the Type drop-down list, select Microsoft Excel Workbook (XLS)

However, on reading it again it appears you may want to open a CSV file, and then save it as an XLS.
choose Data > Import External Data > Import Data
choose Text file in the drop-down list.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I have an webshop which products can be exported to a csv file. The first row are the products discription sku, thumb_image etc. When it can be converted to a normal excel sheet with as first the products description and underneath the products,  would be more then hapy

Comment: @cometbill, your option works allmost, the only strange thing is that excel only let me choose for one delimiter. ie: ca comma. A program module called "CSV IMPORT" let me export the data with as delimiter this: ~^~ 3 characters are used. Can this be done otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

Since CSV, as you write, is just comma separated values of you Excel sheet, it does not contain the information of setup, layout, etc. You will have to do some of this work again.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, Excel is able to open CSV files and, on the process, to give you a chance to define the formats for the columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you use VirtueMart, then I thing it is possible to choose a delimiter in CSV import module setup.

Then you could set up the delimiter to be comma.

Comment: That's correct, but the problem is that they use 2 different delimiters, one as field delimiter and a text delimiter.