# Comma Separated Values in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, csv

Comma separated values are shown in my Excel file in a single cell.

I tried by changing the following value at

`Control Panel --> Regional and Language Options --> Regional Options --> Customize --> List Separator`

but no hope.

My Excel file shows as 
[image]

Comment: exact duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/86423/csv-to-excel-sheet-again?rq=1

Comment: See this post, particularly the Text to Columns solution: http://superuser.com/a/352440/76571

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using Text to Columns?

1. Highlight the column that contains your list.
2. Go to **Data** > **Text to Columns**.
3. Choose **Delimited**. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
4. Choose **Comma**. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>.
5. Choose **General** or **Text**, whichever you prefer.
6. Leave **Destination** as is, or choose another column. Click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.